# How can I improve Tomcat startup time when I have a long running Ehcache initialization?

Tags: tomcat, ehcache

On server startup Ehcache executes some pre-cache work which can take minutes. This is making server restarts inefficient. I would like to be able run the pre-cache task in parallel if possible so it doesn't stop my server from starting. Is this possible or are there better solutions?

Comment: Where and how do you trigger the cache initialization? It should be possible to move this elsewhere

Comment: its an XML based configuration which triggers the intialization. is it possible to delay this or atleast remove the blocking nature of server starting?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ehcache are you using? Ehcache 2 used to ping home at startup. And if home is not available is waits until timeout.

Try setting `updateCheck="false"` in your `ehcache.xml` is that is the case.

Comment: using version 1.6.2